# Twitter Bootstrap 3 apply hover only on table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap to style my table. Is there a way of modifying the table-hover class so that it only highlights the mouseovered cell and not the entire row?  I tried some work-arounds with jquery:

```
 $('.date').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).addClass('active'); },
            function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            });
```

This successfully adds/removes the 'active' class to the cell but it doesn't change the colour of it. When I inspected the element, the cell was picking up the default background colour that is set when the table is painted and the bootstrap 'active' property was crossed out (see pic).

[image]

The reason  why I am using this approach is because I do not initially know what the current cell colour is (the cells pick up a different colour depending on a condition when the table is painted) so I can't know what colour to specify for the mouse-out function.

Comment: this is probably a custom css change

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the dev tools, bootstrap adds this property when hovering over a `tr` element:

```
.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>td, .table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>th{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

What you need to do is:

1. Reset the bootstrap style in order to remove the `hover` effect.
2. Create your own rule on `hover` on the `td` element and not the `tr`.

In finale, your need to add the following rules:

```
// add your own style on td:hover
.table-hover>tbody>tr>td:hover, .table-hover>tbody>tr>td:hover{
        background-color: #f5f5f5!important; // Or any colour you like
    }

// reset the default bootstrap style on tr:hover
.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>td, .table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>th{
        background-color: inherit;
    }
```

---

**Note:** The `!important` part is here to be sure to override the original rule.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tow14t1v/)

**Edit** If you want to keep the original hover and add another one on the actual cell, just add the first rule in the previous answer. See the [alternative fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tow14t1v/1/).